# routes having the same name using the `:as` option - devise custom paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to use custom paths for the registration and session with Devise.

My problem is that the routes can't have the same `'as'`.

My code is this:

```
 #Devise
  devise_for :users, skip: [:sessions,:registration]

  as :user do
    get 'signup', to: 'users/registrations#new', as: :new_user_registration
    post 'signup', to: 'users/registrations#create', as: :user_registration
    get 'edit', to: 'users/registrations#edit', as: :edit_user_registration
    put 'edit', to: 'users/registrations#update' , as: :user_registration
    get 'signin', to: 'users/sessions#new', as: :new_user_session
    post 'signin', to: 'users/sessions#create', as: :user_session
    delete 'signout', to: 'users/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session
  end
```

How you can see the problem is the `put` request for `'edit'` has to have the same `as:` as the post

How can I fix this? with a match?

Comment: Why can't they have same name? They actually can have same name unless they are mapped with same *HTTP* verb which is not your case.

Comment: @Paven `Invalid route name, already in use: 'user_registration' You may have defined two routes with the same name using the ':as' option` is the Rails error.

Comment: Ah, ok. Apologies! Although you cannot use `match` here as they are mapped to different `controller#action`

Answer (score 1):

```
devise_for :users, skip: [:sessions, :registrations, :passwords]

devise_scope :user do
# sessions


get    'login',  to: 'devise/sessions#new',     as: :new_user_session
  post   'login',  to: 'devise/sessions#create',  as: :user_session
  delete 'logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session
  # registrations
  put    '/account',  to: 'devise/registrations#update'
  delete '/account',  to: 'devise/registrations#destroy'
  post   '/account',  to: 'devise/registrations#create'
  get    '/register', to: 'devise/registrations#new',    as: :new_user_registration
  get    '/account',  to: 'devise/registrations#edit',   as: :edit_user_registration
  patch  '/account',  to: 'devise/registrations#update', as: :user_registration
  get    '/account/cancel', to: 'devise/registrations#cancel', as: :cancel_user_registration# passwords 
  # passwords
  get   'new-pass',  to: 'devise/passwords#new',    as: :new_user_password
  get   'edit-pass', to: 'devise/passwords#edit',   as: :edit_user_password
  patch 'edit-pass', to: 'devise/passwords#update', as: :user_password
  post  'new-pass',  to: 'devise/passwords#create', as: :user_password
end
```

check the code below for customizing devise routes

Answer (score 0):

According to the naming conventions, your `patch/put` helper should be named `user_registration` as you have done already, and you `post` helper should be named `user_registrations`, that's to say in the plural form.
Please, check out the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default to be more confident in rails routing DSL and routing conventions.